# Xcode 13 Preparing iOS Device Failed to prepare device for development

Tags: xcode, deployment

I am trying to set up a new MacBook Pro M1 Max. I have been using the same phone with my previous MBP 2018 Intel.

I installed Xcode 13 for M1. When I plug this iPhone 13 Pro Max into this new MBP and open the device manager I get the error that it can't prepare the device for development.

Another piece of info: I am still able to build and deploy my app to the phone from Xcode on this MBP.

I have received this error from time to time on my old laptop and when that happens I just restart the phone and it will work. I tried that with this laptop and that didn't change anything. I don't know if it is exactly the same error as before though.

Here are the details from the error:

````
Details

Failed to prepare device for development.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: 806
Recovery Suggestion: If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.
User Info: {
    AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
    DVTDeviceErrorIsProxied = 1;
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
}
--
The device rejected the pairing attempt.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653035
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000095)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000017b3c2ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000017b3fc3bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000017b3fcdb0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b7ebac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b8de00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
    5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000017b3fcb20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
    6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000017b2a5850 __43-[DVTiOSDevice prepareProxiedDevicesAsync:]_block_invoke + 584
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101da6238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101da7824 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 564
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b7ce60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b7ebac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b86330 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b86ea4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4b91708 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a4d395b0 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a4d382c4 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.0.1 (Build 21A559)
Xcode 13.1 (19466) (Build 13A1030d)
Timestamp: 2021-11-13T16:59:37-07:00```
````

Comment: Message says: 

"This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running."

Have you tried updating XCode?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am pretty sure I have the latest xcode, but will check. If there is an OS that is newer than the released xcode then that would make sense.

Comment: Did you solve this, pal? I'm facing same issue here.

Comment: Not really. I still get it and sometimes a reboot works and other times I have to turn off my watch. It always gets stuck when it tries to load debug symbols from the watch that is paired to the phone.